# Symfony setup issue

Tags: php, symfony, localhost

I am new in Symfony.
I am trying to setup a Symfony Project (Previously Developed) in my Localhost. In this regard I am getting an error

`Fatal error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found in D:\php\htdocs\my_project\app\AppKernel.php on line 22`

Could anyone say what is the solution ??

Thanks

Comment: it means you didn't follow the install instructions for FOSuserbundle correctly

Comment: Could you describe in what step(s) you get that error?

Comment: Thanks @lxer for your quick response. What should I do in this regard ?? Thanks

Comment: I think its already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236651/fos-userbundle-fosuserbundle-not-found

Comment: @0x1337 , I just put the project codes in htdocs of xampp and try to browse the project like  

`http://localhost/my_project/web`

Thanks

Comment: @rijndael thanks for your reply. I tried your solution. But the error is still displaying.

Answer (score 1):

appkernel is probably ok, but something went wrong with the install.
Remove the folder (vendor/friends... etc) and install it again.

```
php composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @lxer for your reply. I got following result

D:\php\htdocs\my_project>php D:\php\php\composer.phar update friendsofsymfony
/user-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to
  have the extension providing it.

  - symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library
    icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to
    have the extension providing it.
  - symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library
    icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure to
    have the extension providing it.
  - Installation request for symfony/icu == 1.2.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/
    icu[v1.2.0].

Comment: that seems to be a different issue. (so the FOS stuff is solved.) Set the correct version symfony/icu  in the composer file, 1.2.0 is not working for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @lxer. I tried your solution and found below results.

D:\php\htdocs\my_project>php D:\php\php\composer.phar update symfony/icu

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle (dev-master d33c5d0)
    Cloning d33c5d0ece19f5758f4bc6679f26e4fdd17d7f49

- Installing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (dev-master 10894cb)
  Cloning 10894cba4584c9f37f2f4c374608306fc5761a3f
- Installing friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle (1.5.3)
  Downloading: 100%
- Updating knplabs/doctrine-behaviors dev-master (c78fbb4 => ea0f040)

  [RuntimeException]
    The .git directory is missing from D:\php\htdocs\iHadis\ihadis\vendor\knpla
    bs\doctrine-behaviors, see http://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for more information

  update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock]
   [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-
  progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
   [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [p
  ackagesN]